# kth Frechet derivative

Tags: functional-analysis, derivatives

Let $X$ be a Banach space.
Let $T \in L(X, \mathbb{R})$ and $G \in L_{2}(X, \mathbb{R})$
Assume $G(u):=B(u, u)$
A
The problem is to calculate $d^{(K)}T$ and $d^{(K)}G$ for all $k \ge1$

I'd appreciate seeing the answer and how it is done.

Comment: What have you tried? Do you even know that $dT(x) = T$ for any $x \in X$?

Comment: No I do not. I read about this yesterday and I'd like to see an example worked out in order to understand it better

Comment: To put in context. How much do you know about Frechet-derivatives? Where did you read about this?

Comment: I know the definition and thats about it. I read it in Nonlinear Analysis and semilinear elliptic equations by Ambrosetti and Malchiodi. Have you heard about it and do you have a copy?

Comment: I now know that $dT(x)=T$ for any $x \in X$ . So the second derivative and subsequent derivates  evaluate to 0. Makes sense once one understands the definitions